# Do something when scrollTop is 0 and it still gets scrolled upwards (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I need:

If you are at the top of the page, like after you reloaded it, the CSS of a specific div shouldn't be changed. Now, if you are scrolling further to the top (even if you are at 0 already), the div should get a style attribute applied with some CSS, whereby the attribute should get removed after you scroll down to 0 again. Does someone have an idea how that works? I've looked up the jQuery API documentation for scrollTop(), but that didn't make anything clearer.

What I've tried so far:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 0){
        $('#profile--heading').css( "height","800px" );
    } else {
        $('#profile--heading').removeAttr("style");
    }
});
```

Basically it's exactly what Google has got for their Google Plus profile heading pictures. If you are at the top of the page, the image should get bigger and after you scroll down again, the website first should scroll to 0 before you are able to scroll further.

Thank you in advance for your effort.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Where is "What I have tried"?

Comment: I tried $(window).scroll(function(){ ... }); and then set the scrollTop to -1 through an if-statement

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your question this might help you: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/flosommerfeld/2w5eh6an/3/)

```
  $(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); //current scroll position
      if (scroll >= 100) {
        $("#block").height(1000);//increases the height of the element
      } else if (scroll < 100) {
        $("#block").height(200);//decreases the height of the element
      }
    });
  });
```